# What is the difference between s.lower().count("earth") and s.upper().count("Earth")?

Tags: python

Today I received a task to count word "earth" in a text using python-3. I know for sure that I have to use `s.count` but in text the word is written in both upper and lower registers. I found out that `s.lower().count("earth")` is what I need, but I don't understand why `s.upper().count("earth")` or `s.lower().count("Earth")` or `s.upper().count("Earth")` do not? I just need an explanation. Here is the text:

```
s = "In a distant, but not so unrealistic, future\
 where mankind has abandoned earth because it has\
 become covered with trash from products sold by\
 the powerful multi-national Buy N Large corporation,\
 WALLE, a garbage collecting robot has been left to\
 clean up the mess. Mesmerized with trinkets of Earth's\
 history and show tunes, WALLE is alone on Earth except\
 for a sprightly pet cockroach. One day, EVE, a sleek\
 (and dangerous) reconnaissance robot, is sent to Earth to\
 find proof that life is once again sustainable."
```

Comment: Everything except s.lower().count("earth") as a result gives 0 (zero) intead of 4 (There are four words "Earth" in the text).

Comment: What do you think `s.lower()` and `s.upper()` do? How could you find "earth" in a text with only uppercase characters. Try `s.upper().count("EARTH")`.

Comment: Of cource I might be wrong because I am a beginner, but as far as I know s.lower() means lower register and s.upper() upper. When I try s.count("Earth"), as a result I get 3 (number of word "Earth" starting only with uppercase character). That is what I am asking. What is the difference between s.lower().count("earth") and just s.count("Earth")

Comment: Concerning "I need an explanation": You can find [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and [`upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) in the documentaion.

Comment: You can also use multi-line string literal syntax. `"""string goes here"""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `s.lower()` your string became it :

> in a distant, but not so unrealistic, future where mankind has
> abandoned earth because it has become covered with trash from products
> sold by the powerful multi-national buy n large corporation, walle, a
> garbage collecting robot has been left to clean up the mess.
> mesmerized with trinkets of earth's history and show tunes, walle is
> alone on earth except for a sprightly pet cockroach. one day, eve, a
> sleek (and dangerous) reconnaissance robot, is sent to earth to find
> proof that life is once again sustainable.

in this text not exists EARTH because all character is lower case

also when you use `s.uper()`:

> IN A DISTANT, BUT NOT SO UNREALISTIC, FUTURE WHERE MANKIND HAS
> ABANDONED EARTH BECAUSE IT HAS BECOME COVERED WITH TRASH FROM PRODUCTS
> SOLD BY THE POWERFUL MULTI-NATIONAL BUY N LARGE CORPORATION, WALLE, A
> GARBAGE COLLECTING ROBOT HAS BEEN LEFT TO CLEAN UP THE MESS.
> MESMERIZED WITH TRINKETS OF EARTH'S HISTORY AND SHOW TUNES, WALLE IS
> ALONE ON EARTH EXCEPT FOR A SPRIGHTLY PET COCKROACH. ONE DAY, EVE, A
> SLEEK (AND DANGEROUS) RECONNAISSANCE ROBOT, IS SENT TO EARTH TO FIND
> PROOF THAT LIFE IS ONCE AGAIN SUSTAINABLE.

all character is upper and not exsists  Earth

Answer (score 1):

Calling `s.lower()` will make your string s all in lower case letters. On a string of all small letters you then call `count("earth")` because there are no capital letters left in your string.